# Windows phone 8 file storage C++

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cli

i'm beginning in C++ Windows phone.
Currently i'm doing a windows phone app with many pages and i don't know how to save and load my data. I tried global variables and SQLite database but i always meet errors so i tried " **Windows::Storage::ApplicationDataContainer** " but i can't pass the variable between all pages.
is there someone who have a template that use ApplicationDataContainer or someone who could explain me how to use it?

here is my code

MainPage.xaml.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include "menu.xaml.h"

using namespace japanEasy;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace std;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

ApplicationDataContainer^ localSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings;
// Pour en savoir plus sur le modèle d'élément Page vierge, consultez la page http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoqué lorsque cette page est sur le point d'être affichée dans un frame.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Données d'événement décrivant la manière dont l'utilisateur a accédé à cette page.  La propriété Parameter
/// est généralement utilisée pour configurer la page.</param>
void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    (void) e;   // Paramètre non utilisé
}

void japanEasy::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{               
    if (this->theName->Text == "" || this->theName->Text == nullptr)
    {
        auto msgDlg = ref new MessageDialog("Vous devez d'abord saisir votre nom", "Attention");
        msgDlg->ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        auto values = localSettings->Values;
        values->Insert("playerName", dynamic_cast<PropertyValue^>(PropertyValue::CreateString(this->theName->Text)));
        String^ value = safe_cast<String^>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("playerName"));
        this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::menu::typeid), localSettings);
    }
}
```

menu.xaml.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "menu.xaml.h"
#include "learn.xaml.h"
#include "level.xaml.h"
#include "records.xaml.h"
#include "easyGame.xaml.h"

using namespace japanEasy;    
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

ApplicationDataContainer^ localSettings ;
menu::menu()
{
    InitializeComponent();      
    this->myName->Text = safe_cast<String^>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("playerName"));
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoqué lorsque cette page est sur le point d'être affichée dans un frame.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Données d'événement décrivant la manière dont l'utilisateur a accédé à cette page.
/// Ce paramètre est généralement utilisé pour configurer la page.</param>
void menu::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    (void) e;   // Paramètre non utilisé
    auto localSettings = (ApplicationDataContainer^)e->Parameter;
    ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page::OnNavigatedTo(e);

}


void japanEasy::menu::goToLearn_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::learn::typeid));
}


void japanEasy::menu::goTo_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

}


void japanEasy::menu::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::level::typeid));
}


void japanEasy::menu::goToRecords_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::records::typeid));
}
```

when i launch my application on my windows phone i seize my username and i click on my button to show the "menu.xaml" page, and i'm supposed to have get the name in this page thanks to the "localSettings" i've passed on my MainPage.xaml.cpp with the naavigate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data from a page to another i used "Page::OnNavigatedTo" method.
So on my menuPage I created a global variable and i added a menu::OnNavigatedTo()
where i get data  from previous pages.
here is my menuPage.xaml.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "menu.xaml.h"
#include "learn.xaml.h"
#include "level.xaml.h"
#include "records.xaml.h"
#include "easyGame.xaml.h"
#include "mediumGame.xaml.h"
#include "hardGame.xaml.h"
#include "Constants.h"

using namespace japanEasy;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace std;
using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace Windows::Phone::UI::Input;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

ApplicationDataContainer^ menuLocalSetting;
String^ lv = "Facile";

// Create a composite setting
ApplicationDataCompositeValue^ recordList = ref new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();

menu::menu()
{
InitializeComponent();  
HardwareButtons::BackPressed += ref new EventHandler<BackPressedEventArgs ^>(this, &menu::HardwareButtons_BackPressed);
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoqué lorsque cette page est sur le point d'être affichée dans un frame.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Données d'événement décrivant la manière dont l'utilisateur a accédé à cette page.
/// Ce paramètre est généralement utilisé pour configurer la page.</param>
void menu::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    //(void) e; // Paramètre non utilisé

if (e->Parameter) {
    menuLocalSetting = safe_cast<ApplicationDataContainer^>(e->Parameter);
    this->myName->Text = safe_cast<String^>(menuLocalSetting->Values->Lookup("userName"));
    auto values = menuLocalSetting->Values;
    if (safe_cast<String^>(menuLocalSetting->Values->Lookup("level"))) {
        String^ value = safe_cast<String^>(menuLocalSetting->Values->Lookup("level"));
        lv = value;
    }
    else {
        auto vvv = menuLocalSetting->Values;
        vvv->Remove("level");
        vvv->Insert("level", dynamic_cast<PropertyValue^>(PropertyValue::CreateString("Facile")));
        String^ test3 = safe_cast<String^>(menuLocalSetting->Values->Lookup("level"));

    }
}
}

void japanEasy::menu::goToLearn_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::learn::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
}

void japanEasy::menu::goTo_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
if(lv == "Facile")
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::easyGame::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
else if(lv =="Moyen")
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::mediumGame::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
else if(lv == "Difficile")
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::hardGame::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
}

void japanEasy::menu::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::level::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
}

void japanEasy::menu::goToRecords_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(japanEasy::records::typeid), menuLocalSetting);
    }

//on ajoute une fonction qui gère la back navigation
void menu::HardwareButtons_BackPressed(Object^ sender, Windows::Phone::UI::Input::BackPressedEventArgs^ e)
{
if (this->Frame->CanGoBack)
{
    //On ferme l'application si l'utilisateur clique sur le bouton back du menu
    Application::Current->Exit();
    e->Handled = true;
}
}
```